# Is it considered normal that -nostdlib does not prevent GCC/Clang to generate calls to C standard library functions?

Tags: gcc, clang, llvm

From `man gcc`:

```
-nostdlib
  Do not use the standard system startup files or libraries when linking.
```

Here we see "when linking". Meaning that `-nostdlib` does not prevent GCC to generate calls to C standard library functions.

Let's check:

```
$ cat t35.c
#define SIZE 4096
char b[SIZE];
void _start(void)
{
  char *p = b;
  int i = SIZE;
  while(i > 0)
  {
    *p = 12;
    ++p;
    --i;
  }
}

$ arm-none-eabi-gcc t35.c -nostdlib -O2
ld.exe: cco83lvm.o: in function `_start':
t35.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `memset'
```

Here we see that ld requires `memset` (because GCC generated `memset`). Hence, the user needs to provide `memset` despite the fact that there is no `memset` in the user's program. For the user it may be confusing.

The same story for Clang: https://godbolt.org/z/jEz77fnf3.

The overall question is simple: is it considered normal that `-nostdlib` does not prevent GCC/Clang to generate calls to C standard library functions?

---

UPD. To prevent generation of certain C standard library functions there is a `-ffreestanding` option:

> Assert that compilation targets a freestanding environment.  This implies
> -fno-builtin.  A freestanding environment is one in which the standard library may not exist, and
> program startup may not necessarily be at "main".  The most obvious example is an OS kernel.  This is equivalent to -fno-hosted.

Demo:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc t35.c -nostdlib -O2 -ffreestanding
<nothing> (expected)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it considered normal that -nostdlib does not prevent GCC/Clang to generate calls to C standard library functions?

Yes. The option is about linking and startup files, not about optimizations. When you use `-nostdlib`, you typically provide and link with your own implementation of `memset`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is documented.  `memset` and a few others are a special case.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Standards.html#Standards

> Most of the compiler support routines used by GCC are present in libgcc, but there are a few exceptions. GCC requires the freestanding environment provide `memcpy`, `memmove`, `memset` and `memcmp`. Finally, if `__builtin_trap` is used, and the target does not implement the trap pattern, then GCC emits a call to `abort`.